# How to convert input to uppercase in groovy

Tags: groovy, case-sensitive, uppercase

I am taking a JSON input and I want it to convert it to uppercase. Can  someone please help me with my code

```
int synchronizeSingleUnit(ApiResultDTO apiResultDTO, def inputJSON, int totalUpdates) {
    def sql = synchronizationApiSqlHelperService.getUnitsSql()
    String unit = getEmptyIfValueNull(inputJSON.unit)

    def session = sessionFactory_apiDb.openSession() as SessionImpl
    def connection = session.connection()
    def sqlConnection = new Sql(connection)

    try {
        sqlConnection.execute(sql, [unit:unit])
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Preload result with statement to be executed
        apiResultDTO.setJsonFailingPart(inputJSON)
        apiResultDTO.setFailedSql(sql, [unit:unit])
        throw new ExceptionWrapper(apiResultDTO, ex)
    } finally {
        session.close()
        connection.close()
    }
```

Comment: What value in that code are you trying to convert to uppercase?

Comment: I am taking input from user for unit.. whatever value it enters I want to update it in my DB in uppercase so that it dont take 2 different values

Comment: `toUpperCase()` allows to convert string to the upper case, as its name suggests. 
More info on this specific as well as other string methods could be found in the [groovy language official documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can use java [String.toUpperCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) as in:

```
String unit = getEmptyIfValueNull(inputJSON.unit)
String uCaseUnit = unit.toUpperCase()
```

< -- edit -- >

As a comment and addition, I don't know the specifics of method `getEmptyIfValueNull` but judging from the name you just want to return an empty string when the expression `inputJSON.unit` returns null.

Groovy has two special operators which make expressions like these easier to write.

- the [safe navigation operator](https://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator) `?.` and
- the [elvis operator](https://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator) `?:` (see how that looks like an Elvis smiley?)

using these two you could rewrite your code somewhat more concisely as:

```
String unit = inputJSON.unit?.toUpperCase() ?: ''
```

explanation:

- `inputJSON.unit?.toUpperCase()` - evaluate `inputJSON.unit` and if that expression returns null, just return null from the entire expression (never executing the `toUpperCase` method). If `inputJSON.unit` returns a non-null value, things work as they would just by using `inputJSON.unit.toUpperCase()`.
- `... ?: ''` - take an expression and if it is not empty string or null,return it, otherwise return the empty string.

Where the first operator `.?` is specifically for handling null values and the second operator `?:` uses [groovy truth](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) which includes, but is more inclusive than just null values.

There are a few ways of writing the above, for example:

```
String unit = (inputJSON.unit ?: '').toUpperCase()
```

but to my mind the first version "flows" better. To each his own.

Comment: Can't I use it directly like this String unit = getEmptyIfValueNull(inputJSON.unit.toUpperCase())

Comment: Yes you can. The point I was trying to make was that groovy has this functionality built into the language making the call unnecessary.